# Different frontend CSS results (Grunt vs deploy:mode:set production)

Tags: frontend, development, grunt

I have a weird issue where the frontend results of a grunt compile are different compared to a compilation after `deploy:mode:set production`. UI elements are different. Why is that?

How can I debug/resolve this?